# Windows 11: Disable Win + Alt + Arrow Keys to snap to top/bottom half

Tags: windows, shortcuts, snap

The new Windows 11 shortcut "Win+Alt+Arrow up/down" is interfering with other software I am using.

Is there perhaps a registry way to disable this specific shortcut?

So far I see that I can only globally disable the whole snapping feature. I quite like it, but this specific one is of no use to me.

Thanks in advance!